# JavaScript remove array

Tags: javascript

I tried doing `delete weapons[i];` but even do when I do `weapons.length` I still get 1. Even though it should be 0. How do I definitely remove an array from `weapons[]` array?

I comb over the weapons array by doing this:

```
        for (var i = 0, setsLen = weapons.length; i < setsLen; ++i ) {

             var searchWeapon = weapons[i].split("|");
             // console.log('['+i+'] >> Weapon ID: ' + searchWeapon[0] + ' | Y: ' + searchWeapon[1] + ' | X: ' + searchWeapon[2]);    
             if (searchWeapon[1] == Y && searchWeapon[2] == X) { 
                delete weapons[i];
             }           
            }
```

and I store each array as `3|10|4` where `3` is weapon ID, `10` is Y, and `4` is X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the .splice method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

**Using your example:**

```
for (var i = 0, setsLen = weapons.length; i < setsLen; ++i ) {
  var searchWeapon = weapons[i].split("|");
  if (searchWeapon[1] == Y && searchWeapon[2] == X) { 
    weapons.splice(i,1);
  }           
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Splice did the trick. Also Splice was a horrible movie.

Comment: Link to [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) not [W3FOOLS](http://w3fools.com/). [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 3):

Use **[splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)**

```
array.splice(index,howmany)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your array doesn't need to be sorted, you could use `array.pop()` as it's extremely fast.

```
if(index == array.length-1) array.pop();
else array[index] = array.pop();
```

This method doesn't need to re-index everything after what you've `splice()'d`, so it remains quick whether your array has a length of 5 or 350,000.

Comment: Nice piece of code. But is this meaningfully faster than `splice` in a real-world context?

Comment: Yes.. A **lot** faster. Well, depending on the length of your array. pop() is always the same speed whereas splice gets slower with the length of the array.

Comment: No probs.. It's more something to keep in mind with game dev when you're listing 500-1000 projectiles and stuff haha.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the answers above:
you should walk the array from the end to the start, otherwise you'll miss elements inside the loop if a item has been removed.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/2f9Ye/

Answer (score 0):

`delete`ing an array element leaves a hole behind with `undefined` left in the element's place. You probably want to use `Array.splice`.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
delete myArray[1]; // myArray is now [1, undefined, 3];

var myArray2 = [1,2,3];
myArray2.splice(1,1); // myArray2 is [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an element from an array use the `splace` method. Example:

```
var myArr = ["apple", "orange", "pear"];
alert(myArr.length); // 3
myArr.splice(1,1); // start at 1th index (i.e 2nd element), remove 1 element
alert(myArr.length); // 2
for (var i=0; i<myArr.length; i++) alert(myArr[i]); // "apple", "pear"
```

Comment: LOLs. Yes, of course: `Array.prototype.splace = Array.prototype.splice;`